# Mysql замена в строке

Tags: mysql, replace

Пытаюсь заменить в строке вот такую часть

```
update pages set text_ro = replace(text_ro, '<p>    &nbsp;</p>','')
```

В базе она так же занесена с пробелами,но в итоге возвращает пустой запрос,как быть?

```
<p>
        &nbsp;</p> - вот так в бд хранится
```

Comment: (1) *"…но в итоге возвращает пустой запрос"* UPDATE это вам не SELECT, он и не должен возвращать записи.

Comment: (2) похоже у вас данные не просто с пробелма, но с переносами строк и, возможно, с табуляциями. я советую выполнить работу на php или другом скриптовом языке, через регулярные выражения или библиотеку разбора XML. mysql не имеет адекватных средств для сложной обработки текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придется в точно повторить структуру ваших пробельных символов (перевод строки и 7 пробелов) для того, чтобы оператор `UPDATE` осуществил замену. Или так

```
UPDATE
  pages
SET
  text_ro = REPLACE(text_ro, '<p>
        &nbsp;</p>', '')
```

Или прописав перевод строки явно

```
UPDATE
  pages
SET
  text_ro = REPLACE(text_ro, '<p>\r\n        &nbsp;</p>', '')
```

К сожалению, MySQL не поддерживает замену при помощи регулярных выражений на уровне `REPLACE()`, поэтому построить более или менее универсальное только средствами MySQL решение довольно трудно.